# Declaring parameters of same type in a function at once

Tags: swift

```
func floatValues(firstValue: CGFloat, secondValue: CGFloat, thirdValue: CGFlot)
{
  first = firstValue
  second = secondValue
  third = thirdValue
}
```

In the above function, is there a way to declare all the `three parameters` at once as `CGFloat` as they are all of the same `type CGFloat`, instead of declaring those three parameters individually?

Comment: Aside from declaring it as an array, there is no built-in syntax sugar for that.

Comment: Nice to know that, I was thinking there may be something built for it.

Comment: readability > brevity

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for a varargs parameter, like

```
func floatValues(values: CGFloat...)
{
  first = values[0]
  second = values[1]
  third = values[2]
}
```

I'm not sure whether saving a couple of named parameters really makes that much of a difference, though.

Comment: I don't think so, I took the refactoring too far.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is not something which is built-in in Swift.
But the most near to it you can use is **Tuples**

```
func floatValues(values: (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat)) {

  first = values.0
  second = values.1
  third = values.2
}
```